# Access view in a fragment from activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

this seems a strange question, but for me is not clear.
I created a simple Android project with an activty and a Fragment.
First question: the fragment is created in the event OnCreate of the Activity with the setContentView, is correct?
Now, why I can set the text (for example) of a TextView that reside in the layout of the fragment?

Can you please clarify the link with Activity fragment?
Thank you!

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

> the fragment is created in the event OnCreate of the Activity with the setContentView, is correct?

We have no way to know, as we do not have your code. A fragment is added to an activity by one of two means:

1. Inflating a layout that contains a `<fragment>` tag, such as via `setContentView()`
2. Committing a `FragmentTransaction`, where you use `add()` or `replace()` to put a fragment in an activity

> why I can set the text (for example) of a TextView that reside in the layout of the fragment?

The activity has access to its entire view hierarchy. Whether those individual views came from a `Fragment` or a `ListAdapter` or a `RecyclerView.Adapter` or anywhere else does not matter.

Now, it is not a good idea to have an activity manipulate the views created by fragments — "separation of concerns" says that the fragment should manage its own views.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly...

You have an activity which has a java file and an xml file. Then you have a fragment which has it's own java file and xml file.

When your activity starts it opens the specified xml file like this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now if you want to use a fragment you should have a frame layout in your activity's xml to be the fragment container. Here is an example of an activity that hosts fragments

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

So it basically has three elements: A tool bar, navigation drawer, and a fragment container.

Now the important thing to understand is that whatever is outside that container in that xml will be shared by all the fragment that I call. So any fragment I call for that activity will also have a toolbar and nav drawer by default.

in the activity's java file you can call a fragment like this (a fragment is not called on create. You have to call it yourself)

```
Fragment firstFragment = new MainFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

so then your fragment is ran and displayed.

Fragments were made to be to split up ui code. So instead of having 20 activities in a program you can have 5 activities and 15 fragments. You can reuse fragments and replace them. The current project I'm working on for example has a main activity that is almost 800 lines long. I don't want to run all those lines of code again every time I switch a screen so I made a bunch of fragments. Main activity is still active and so is a fragment but I can switch between fragments instead of having start and restart a bunch of activities